# c# Winforms can't open minimized form

Tags: c#, winforms, minimize

I have a rather large win forms project that includes a form that opens another form that includes static information for our employees while working on the other form. (I will call the form that is opened the edit form and the informational form the information form for purposes of this question) The problem that I am having is that if they happen to minimize the edit form, they must click on the minimized edit form several times to open it, each time with a ding being heard until it works. This problem is not reproducible in my development environment, but is in the deployed environments including our production and test environments. I have worked backwards commenting out stuff until it went to working, and found that when this information form is accessing the data model is when the problem happens, if I don't let the information form access the datamodel the forms will open up as expected.

Additional Information:

- .Net 4.0
- Information Form includes a user control
- Visual Studio 2013

If anyone has any clue as to what may be causing this issue or something that may help me find this issue it would be much appreciated. I have attempted looking at process monitor to no avail.

Comment: What happens if you release the reference to the data model after you get the info?

Comment: Can you access your data model from another thread?  I know multi-threading in winforms is a pain and sometimes hard to debug but it would free up your UI thread to be responsive.

Comment: The data access is fast, as all it is doing is a quick select from a couple of tables (data access time is under a second), and after this is done it is dynamically adding controls to the information grid based upon the data returned.

Comment: One thing that might make a difference is that this information form is used by any edit form that is open. Such that if I have 3 different entities of edit form open at 1 time, whichever one is active will set the info form to the data that pertains to that edit form.

Comment: Also, if I do not allow the data model to retrieve the data, basically just instantiate a class and never use it, it still gives me this issue.